# How to determine the architecture of an installation or Live CD/DVD?

Tags: release-management

How can I determine which architecture (x86 or x64) my Ubuntu installation medium is for?

I don't have it installed, I just need to know which files on the installation media I can use to determine the architecture.

Comment: Remember, you can use the live environment to run Ubuntu without installing it...

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate since it does not involve an actual installation.

Comment: @NathanOsman: We can run the live environment and the same solutions would work. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is a \EFI folder on the Iso it is 64-bit, 32-bit does not have a \EFI folder.

Comment: good to know, thanks . You right , i have 2 DVD's with linux, and that dosen't have an EFI Folder . thanks mate <3